# Postfix is reserved error

Tags: swift, parse-platform, io

The below is my code entered to Swift 2 and getting the error saying "postfix is reserved". 
Can anyone tell me how this went wrong?

```
if (PFUser.currentUser() == nil){

self.loginViewController.fields = 
PFLogInFields.UsernameAndPassword | PFLogInFields.LogInButton | PFLogInFields.SignUpButton | PFLogInFields.PasswordForgotten | PFLogInFields.DismissButton
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you ensure that your OR compound expression does not contain spurious spaces?. I can spot one before the .LogInButton. I have corrected it here. Please check-

```
if (PFUser.currentUser() == nil){

self.loginViewController.fields = 
PFLogInFields.UsernameAndPassword | PFLogInFields.LogInButton | PFLogInFields.SignUpButton | PFLogInFields.PasswordForgotten | PFLogInFields.DismissButton
```

Comment: hi I closed the space but it didn't change anything. -Shripada